# What is executed in Docker when no ENTRYPOINT is provided and CMD is used in Exec Form without an executable?

Tags: docker, cmd

Quoting from the [Docker documentation for CMD](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> The CMD instruction has three forms:
>
> CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
>
> These defaults can include an executable, or they can omit the executable, **in which case you must specify an ENTRYPOINT** instruction as well.

And again quoting from the Docker Documentation, this time from [Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact):

> The table below shows what command is executed for different ENTRYPOINT / CMD combinations:

```
                            No ENTRYPOINT
CMD [“p1_cmd”, “p2_cmd”]    p1_cmd p2_cmd
```

I do not understand the intersection I copied above. I would expect the intersection of `CMD [“p1_cmd”, “p2_cmd”]` and `No ENTRYPOINT` to be `error, not allowed` (just like No CMD, No ENTRYPOINT) but the table says `p1_cmd p2_cmd` gets executed. I am assuming `p1_cmd` and `p2_cmd` are parameters, something like `-t` `-a` or whatever..

So what gets executed in this state? Does it mean the parameter becomes the executable?

Comment: According to the git log of Docker repository, `CMD` was there from the very beginning (first mention at Jan 29, 2013), while `ENTRYPOINT` was introduced at Jun 24, 2013. The initial release of Docker (according to Wikipedia) was at March 13, 2013, so `ENTRYPOINT` was introduced *after* the initial release. This means, that new `ENTRYPOINT` directive *probably* had to work so that the existing semantics of `CMD` was left untouched (backwards compatibility). This could explain why `CMD` without `ENTRYPOINT` is a valid option and why in this case the semantics of its first argument is different.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to imagine this is that `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` both define lists of words, and the final command is constructed by just concatenating the two lists together.  Docker has no way of knowing whether or not the first word of the `CMD` list is actually an executable or not.

All three of these run the exact same command when a container is started:

```sh
FROM busybox
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ls"]
CMD ["-lrt", "/"]
```

```sh
FROM busybox
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD ["/bin/ls", "-lrt", "/"]
```

```sh
FROM busybox
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ls", "-lrt", "/"]
CMD []
```

My general experience has been that `CMD` should always be a well-formed command in its own right.  There are two good reasons for this: it is frequently useful to `docker run --rm -it imagename sh` to see what came out of your image build process; and there is a useful pattern of setting `ENTRYPOINT` to a script that does some first-time setup and then `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD`.  (Combine the two and you get a debugging shell after the first-time setup has run.)

```sh
# good
CMD ["/app/myapp", "--foreground"]
```

```sh
# good
ENTRYPOINT ["wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--"]
CMD ["/app/myapp", "--foreground"]
```

```sh
# hard to provide an alternate command or an ENTRYPOINT wrapper
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/myapp"]
CMD ["--foreground"]
```

For practical purposes `ENTRYPOINT` *must* be the JSON-array form and must not use a `sh -c` wrapper.  As the documentation notes, if `ENTRYPOINT` is a bare command then the `CMD` is ignored; if it has an explicit `sh -c` wrapper the interactions with additional arguments aren't obvious.

```sh
# just prints an empty line
FROM busybox
ENTRYPOINT /bin/echo
CMD ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

```sh
# just prints an empty line
FROM busybox
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/echo"]
CMD ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

In fact, `ENTRYPOINT` as a bare string doesn't block `CMD` *per se*; but the resulting `/bin/sh -c 'some command' arg arg` sets `$0`, `$1`, *etc.* inside the command in a way that's not obvious.

```sh
# prints "three"
FROM busybox
ENTRYPOINT echo $2
CMD ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

```sh
# prints "-c"
FROM busybox
ENTRYPOINT echo $1
CMD one two three four
```